# Desplazarme entre componentes (TextBox y Botones) usando TAB

Tags: c#

Tengo un Form hecho en C# con algunos botones y TextBox, se supone que cuando le de a la tecla TAB se cambie al siguiente componente, ya sea un botón o un cuadro de texto, pero a veces se va hasta dos o tres componentes.

No tengo código

[image: Este es el formulario]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En visual studio, cuando estás en el diseñador de formularios:

```
Menu Ver/View -> Orden de tabulación
```

Y luego simplemente vas dando click en cada control en el orden que lo quieres.

Answer (score 0):

te comento lo que maneja el orden los tabs, es el TabIndex, el cual es una propiedad en los controles.

```
public int TabIndex { get; set; }
```

yendo de menor a a mayor 0,1,2,3,4 etc.

Puedes cambiarlo por vista de diseño o mediante código.

Código

```
button1.TabIndex = 1;
```

Diseño

Cambiar valor de TabIndex

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

en esta parte lo puedes cambiar mas facilmente, o por lo menos yo siempre lo hice asi...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nota: es donde dice TabIndex...

espero te sirva bro... y la marques By: JJ